# Integer solution to linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, examples-counterexamples, matrix-rank

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is a fat matrix ($n<m$) with full rank, and that all elements of $A$ are $1,-1$ or $0$. Given an integer vector $b \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, does there exist an **integer** vector $x \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ such that $Ax = b$?

Comment: You may be interested in the notion of [unimodular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix), and in particular totally unimodular matrices.

Comment: No, the solution does not always exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$A=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&-1}$$
and
$$b=\pmatrix{1\\0}.$$
Any integer vector solution to $Ax=b$?